# Autocovariance of Explosive AR(1) model with $|\phi|>1$ expressed as a stationary process

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, stationarity, autoregressive

I am working through the book called Time Series Analysis and Its Applications by Shumway and Stoffer. I am stuck deriving an equation given in example 3.4 in the book (page 80 for the fourth edition), which I describe below. Now I do know a similar question was asked before (here: [Autocovariance for an explosive AR(1) process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563024/autocovariance-for-an-explosive-ar1-process)), but I do not really get that response nor what is wrong with the derivation I show below.

Let us consider an AR(1) process that has $|\phi|>1$, also called an "Explosive AR(1)" process
$$
x_t = \phi x_{t-1}+w_t,\;\;\;\;w_t \sim N(0,\sigma_w^2)
$$

I know we can rewrite this as a "stationary process" as follows:
$$
x_t = -\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\phi^{-j}w_{t+j}
$$

Now, I am trying to verify the equations that were given for the autocovariance of an Explosive AR(1) model. According to the book, the autocovariance for this explosive process is: $\gamma{(k)}=\sigma_w^2 \phi^{-2} \phi{-h} / (1-\phi^{-2})$.

However, when I try to derive this by myself, I get a slightly different equation. I will give my derivation below, and if anyone can show me what I did wrong, that would be great (or if I am right, and the equation in the book is wrong)!

\begin{align}
\gamma_x(h)&=cov(x_{t+h},x_t)=cov\Big(-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\phi^{-j}w_{t+h+j},-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi^{-k}w_{t+k}\Big) \\
&= E\Bigg[\Big(-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\phi^{-j}w_{t+h+j}\Big)\Big(-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi^{-k}w_{t+k}\Big)\Bigg]\\
&= E\Big[\big(-\phi^{-1}w_{t+h+1}-\phi^{-2}w_{t+h+2}-\phi^{-3}w_{t+h+3}-...\big) \big(-\phi^{-1}w_{t+1}-...-\phi^{-h-1}w_{t+h+1}-\phi^{-h-2}w_{t+h+2}-\phi^{-h-3}w_{t+h+3}-...\big)\Big]\\
&=\phi^{-1}\phi^{-h-1}E(w_{t+h+1}^2)+\phi^{-2}\phi^{-h-2}E(w_{t+h+2}^2)+\phi^{-3}\phi^{-h-3}E(w_{t+h+3}^2)+...\\
&=\phi^{-h-2}\sigma_w^2+\phi^{-h-4}\sigma_w^2+\phi^{-h-6}\sigma_w^2+...\\
&=\sigma_w^2 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \phi^{-h-2j}\\
&=\sigma_w^2\phi^{-h} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \phi^{-2j}\\
&=\sigma_w^2\phi^{-h}\Bigg[ \frac{1}{1-\phi^{-2}}\Bigg]\\
\end{align}

I used the result for a geometric series in the last step because $|\phi|^{-2}<1$.

What I derived is close, but not the same to what the authors put in the book. Can someone verify what I did above, or I made a mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is $|\theta|\lt1$ used in recursive method derivation of invertibility of MA(1)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535533/where-is-theta1-used-in-recursive-method-derivation-of-invertibility-of-ma)

Comment: I read through that, but I do not know if it helps me. I get that with $|\phi|>1$ the AR model explodes, which is why you have to do this trick to express it as a infinite sum of future values of $x$, and thus it is not causal. My issue was in the derivation of the autocovariance missing a $\phi^{-2}$ that the author of the textbook got when try to fill in the blanks in one of his steps.

Comment: In that case I think [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563024/) is probably what you're after.  It is asking about the exact same issue in the same book.